# How to turn a kafkacat payload printout into binary

Tags: apache-kafka, kcat

I can use `kafkacat` to get a tuple from a topic and print it out:

```
kafkacat -b kafka10.myorg.com:9092 -t MyTopic -o -1 -f '%s\n'
```

And I get something like this in my terminal:

```
�ǐے�ғ�����������ǐے�ғ���������S1_153314S3_153314S4_5422973S2_5420991...
```

Is it possible for me to convert the printed out payload to binary format so I can feed that to my local code to debug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can consume the messages directly as binary data without applying formatting.

```
kafkacat -b kafka10-staging.salesforceiq.com:9092 -t MyTopic -o -1 -D "" > out.file
```

The usage of -D "" is there to avoid adding the "\n" to the binary data.
https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/issues/72

Comment: Unless the messages contains a length or delimiter to allow separating messages in the file, you might want to append the length of each message by `-f %R%s`

Comment: It makes sense that I'd want to prefix each payload with something, but I was thinking it would be something constant so I could use something like awk's record separator to split the payloads back apart. @Edenhill would you mind explaining how you would make use of the payload length printed in the output? I like the idea, I'm just not sure how to take advantage of it.